# How to print a nested std::map using gdb?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

My program has a nested  `std::map` object like

```
map < int, set < void *> *> m;
```

My program coredown in some situation, and I don't know the reason. 
I suspect the problem is in  the nested map.

I only know using pmap to print simple map objects like `std::map<int, int>`,
but don't know how to print more complicated map objects.

If a map is defined as `map< int, int > m;`, then

```
gdb pmap m int int
```

does work, but if a map is  defined as

```
map< int, set < void * > * > m;
```

then

```
gdb pmap m int set < void *> *
```

does not work

Comment: Or is the inner `std::set` the problem and `p m` does not work? If so, please comment, then this should probably be reopened, but you should clarify how `p m` does not work, i.e. what goes wrong.

Comment: if a map is map<int, int> m ,  pmap m int int does work, but is a map is map<int, set<void *> *> m, pmap m int  set<void *> * does not work

Comment: I can't see any "nested map" here.